# AJAX call not returning on second click via MVC controller when previous call is still running

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a number of buttons on a view that make a call to the same controller via jquery and ajax, the first button press fires the ajax and calls the controller (MVC) however clicking another button during that time results in the controller being fired but not returning/processing by the ajax?

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Downloads/RequestDownload/',
        type: 'post',
        data: { parameter1: obj.data('ou'), parameter2: obj.data('asset'), parameter3: obj.data('report-type'), parameter4: obj.data('appservice'), parameter5: obj.data('filetype') },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.indexOf('ERROR') ==-1)
            {
                obj.addClass('blue');
                obj.removeClass('red');
                window.location = '/Downloads/DownloadReport/' + data;
                obj.html(ohtml);
                obj.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        }
});
```

It only seems to be a problem when it tries to hit the controller whilst still running the previous call?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? Or what are you using on the server side? The problem is most likely there.

Comment: @tereško: Are you sure it's ASP.NET MVC indeed? I'm still uncertain.

Comment: @Codo for about 99%. Because of user's history and the use of camel-cased URLs. It's a shame that these people do not understand the difference between architectural pattern and a framework. I guess MS marketing department would call it "a win".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using ASP.NET MVC on the server side, you have most likely run into the ASP.NET session lock.

By default, the access to the session is limited to a single action at a time. That's why the second request is blocked as long as the first one is still running.

To work around it, you can use the `SessionState` attribute of the controller, set the access mode to *read only* and thereby allowing concurrent session access:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ....
```

The possible values for the session state behavior are found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatebehavior%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

An advanced approach is to configure the [session access behavior by action](http://sapoval.org/per-action-custom-sessionstateattribute).